# Loss of data structure upon program termination

Tags: data-structures

A data structure is used to store information first and foremost. In introductory CS courses, a popular application is a database of people - employees, students, or club members. In a linked list implementation, each node would contain 'name', 'id', 'age', etc, and there would be function 'insert' that prompts the user the enter each person's info one by one, when the program is run.

Such a data structure is usually dynamically allocated on the heap, so when the program terminates, all the data is lost. So is an employee directory really a real-word application of the linked-list data structure? And if so, how do we deal with the fact the data is lost upon program exit?

Comment: The temporary structures used during program execution are serialized using some.method. The exact way structures are serialized is dependant upon many factors, so it's difficult to say how a given structure will "look" when saved to the disk.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. In typical [n-tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), data is stored in a separate permanent storage area. Data is generally only held in RAM as objects while that data is being processed - otherwise it is offloaded to the data store. Commonly this is a Relational DataBase Management System (RDBMS) such as Oracle or SQL Server, but it can also be a spreadsheet, a text file, or anything that can represent saved data. If data is stored in a text file, a delimiting language or system may be used to provide structure - examples are Comma Separated Value (CSV) files and XML. In olden days of yore, data was stored as punched cards or Punched Paper Tape (PPT).

The process of saving data in memory to a form that is easier to preserve is sometimes called *serialization*. Deserialization is the opposite process - to take that translated data and turn it back into the original (or an equivalent of the original) data in memory, such as linked lists, tuples, bitmapped images, stacks, arrays, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The point of teaching the employee directory design through Linked list or any other dynamically allocated data structure is to make you understand how real world applications are designed from different perspective. When you use dynamically allocated memory its true you will loss the data once its done execution but the focus of the topic is not on what happen after execution but what happen during execution. As you will learn through your semester that the real world challenges occur during execution like performance related issue, wrong data structure selection flaws, memory constraints,etc and to overcome this you need to be good at understanding how different DS works with memory. Why we use hashmap over array or linklist and  when vice versa.

Now coming back to your specific question, No you will not lose your data as the real world employee directory are build around [Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) so before your program execution finished, your data will be stored in some form your database understands for [persistent storage](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/Persistent-storage). From there your stored data will be pulled in-out in memory as and when required for processing which might include linkList DS again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that already your understanding of terms is inappropriate.

In CS / IT a **database** is a component that does provide **persistence** for data. That's the whole point of a **database** - it makes sure your data isn't lost when some process ends, or some computer is switched off.

The thing is: when you start programming and learning about **data types** and **data structures**, of course, *linked lists* are one of the first things you hear about. And then you apply that knowledge by building an application that allows a user to enter data; to then do something with that (like printing, searching, creating statistics). But by purpose, all of that is gone when your first program ends.

The simple reason for that: **persistence** adds a whole lot of complexity to **anything** that you do in your program. So, for simple **educational** purposes you start of with "memory-only" applications.

And then, when you mastered that; then you go one step further and deal with questions like "OK, now what means exist to avoid entering the data again and again upon restarting my program?"